# how to get rid of the PHP form redirect

Tags: php, html, mysql

After inserting data into MySQL, i get redirected to the PHP file. not cool! How do i display error or success messages in the same HTML file.

index.html

```
<form id="form" action="add_article.php" method="post">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="title" name="title"><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="author" name="author"><br/><br/>
            <textarea placeholder="article summary" rows="12" maxlength="300" name="description"></textarea><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="location e.g. lubaga cathedral" name="location"><br/><br/>
        </div>
</form>
```

.

add_article.php

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bookdb");

    if (!$con){
        die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error($con));
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO article (title, author, description,location)
    VALUES('$_POST[title]','$_POST[author]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[location]')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        echo "Article inserted";
    else
        echo "An Error was Encountered";
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Yesigye.

Comment: Just so you note that there is no REDIRECT involved here at all.  You are POSTing the data from index.html to add_article.php.  You can look at the suggestion from @matthielo to get a better idea of how to handle this all in a single page.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best and shortest way is to work with a single file, `add_article.php`:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['title'])){

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bookdb");

    if (!$con){
        die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error($con));
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO article (title, author, description,location)
    VALUES('$_POST[title]','$_POST[author]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[location]')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        echo "Article inserted";
    else
        echo "An Error was Encountered";
    mysqli_close($con);

}
?>
<form id="form" action="add_article.php" method="post">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="title" name="title"><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="author" name="author"><br/><br/>
            <textarea placeholder="article summary" rows="12" maxlength="300" name="description"></textarea><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="location e.g. lubaga cathedral" name="location"><br/><br/>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You might want to use redirect, to avoid the form post refresh issue(resubmitting the form with the same data when someone refresh the browser).

Comment: Maybe not the best, but probably the shortest. Also OP should take care of sql-injection - threats.

Comment: @Vincent Note that such an approach also makes it more difficult to repopulate the erroneous entries; you would have to use a session to keep track of the old values.

Comment: Good point @Vincent. You may still have just one file, but instead of echoing the success/error message, redirect to the same page as `add_article.php?msg=Thank you!` or, better yet, `add_article.php?msgId=1`

Answer (score 1):

You can either do what @relentless said:

```
if(article is inserted)
{
echo header('location:www.example.com');
}
```

Or using meta refresh:

```
if(article is inserted)
{
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL="www.example.com" />';
}
```

On error you use the above to redirect to an error page, or merely use else{} to display an error message:

```
else
{
 //redirect
 echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL="www.example.com/errorpage" />';
//or
echo 'Error: '.mysqli_error($con);
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp